# Why does tsc.exe (TypeScript compiler) add var _this = this; as the first line in the output js files?

Tags: typescript

We use tsc.exe to compile out `.ts` files into the respective `.js` files. For some reason, the TypeScript compiler adds `var _this = this;` as the first line in the produced file.

For example:

```
declare var define;
define({
});
```

is compiled into

```
var _this = this;
define({
});
```

The compiler invoked with an args file like this:

```
--comments --module AMD --target ES5
"c:\abc\Scripts\Framework\Modules\Store\TreeStoreMixin.ts" "c:\abc\Scripts\Framework\Client\AppBulletin.ts" ...
```

(The file is truncated for the sake of brevity)

Why? I would understand if `this` was referring an outer function, so `_this` would have been capturing its scope. But this is a global file level scope, isn't it? `this` is not useful here. Can I instruct the compiler not to generate it?

Comment: What version of the compiler are you using? The flag hasn't been `--comments` for a while now.

Comment: Bug in the compiler. Highly recommend upgrading to 0.9.7 (1.0 Release Candidate).

Comment: Is there a download with tsc.exe?

Comment: http://www.typescriptlang.org/#Download

Comment: I was there. I do not see a download with tsc.exe. There is a node package without tsc.exe, there is a Visual Studio plugin and there is a link to source code (I am there now, trying to download the source code). I could not find any sign of a download with tsc.exe prepackaged.

Comment: BTW, trying to download the source code of release-0.9.7 gives this lovely message: 

**Gateway Timeout**

The proxy server did not receive a timely response from the upstream server.
Reference #1.61020ecf.1395782832.c3bc21f

Comment: The Visual Studio plugin includes tsc.exe and does not require VS to be installed

Comment: OK, I will check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the latest version of the compiler, your code compiles to:

```
define({});
```

You will find valid use of `_this` in your output in the latest version of the compiler, but only where you are using fat-arrow syntax, for example...

```
class Example {
    constructor(public name: string) {

    }

    // _this variable will be defined before here
    public eventHandler = () =>{    
        // will be _this.name in output
        alert(this.name);
    }
}

var example = new Example('mark');

window.setTimeout(example.eventHandler, 1000);
```

I suspect there is a bug in the older compiler you are using that is mistakenly generating the `_this` variable when it isn't actually needed.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not in a position to upgrade - there are too many of incompatibilities between the old and the new version. It is beyond my mandate at the moment.